# Go back up a line in psql

Tags: psql

In psql, I want to go back up a line and edit my SQL from the line above. How would I accomplish this? I tried the up arrow to no avail. My only recourse is to exit psql and jump back in. [image]

For some context:

I want to go back to the line above and change `SET dw1 = TRUE`

I am ssh'd into the server using gitbash for windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't finished the command. Notice how the first line ends with `=#` while the second line ends with `-#`, which indicates that it's awaiting further text.

You need to end the command with a semicolon (`;`).

Once you're at a new line that starts with `=#` you can press up to retrieve the previous command.

Here's an example where I entered `select 1<ENTER>` followed by `;<ENTER>` followed by `<UP>`:

```
db=# select 1
db-# ;
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)

db=# select 1
;
```